# Implicit Declaration of Function 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration' is invalid in C99 error

Tags: objective-c, c99

So, I mainly write in swift, but it seems that the only way to call this 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration' is in Objective-c... At the beginning, The code I wrote did work, I am not sure what changed but it gives me the error "Implicit Declaration of Function 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration' is invalid in C99" now instead of just a warning. Same warning and error title, but now that it is an error I can't compile. Yes, I know that I am using a private API, but I do not plan to sell the app so I don't care what apple thinks. I just need to have custom vibrates. The two functions vibrateMutate and vibrateSection are both called in separate swift files, and I put the 'import vibrate.h' in the Bridging Header that I was coxed to create when I made my objective-c files. Here is my code :)

```
//vibrate.h FILE NAME

#ifndef vibrate_h
#define vibrate_h
@interface  Vibrate : NSObject

+ (void)vibrateMutate;
+ (void)vibrateSectionChange;

@end



#endif /* vibrate_h */

// vibrate.m FILE NAME

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#import "vibrate.h"

@implementation Vibrate

+ (void) vibrateMutate
{
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array ];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:50]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];


[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:.25] forKey:@"Intensity"];

AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict); //ERROR
}

+ (void) vibrateSectionChange
{
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array ];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:150]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];


[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:.75] forKey:@"Intensity"];

AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the call is right and just want to satisfy the compiler, you can give an explicit definition in your code.  I don't know what the correct definition of the private function is but the following should work if you don't care about being precise.

```
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(int, id, id);

@implementation Vibrate
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record to add some extra value to the nice answer by @PhilipMills, Apple Store will never accept any binary which references any Apple's non-public symbols or private APIs. They reject the binary automatically with the following message:

> **Non-public API usage:**
>
> - The app references non-public symbols in JustIN Mobile: _AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration
>
> If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs
> listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app
> from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one
> or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was
> included with your app. If so, they must be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the input, yeah, we know that we won't be able to submit to the App Store, but this was a personal project, so we weren't too worried about it. :)

Comment: No worries, I know you mentioned in your question, but there always are distracted people who don't know the implications and maybe this could save some time to them ;-)