# How to make haptic in dynamic island?

Tags: ios, swift, haptic-feedback, dynamic-island

In iOS17 dynamic island have capable to interactive with `Button` and `Toggle` .I wish to make a haptic effect when tap the button in dynamic island.

The normal solution **NOT working** in dynamic island like`UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.init(style: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator.FeedbackStyle.light).impactOccurred()`.

After I make a lot of trying,I find the oldest way to generate a haptic——`AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))`is still working.

But the problem is **does AudioServicesPlayAlertSound can play a short haptic?**

The answer is Yes!

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer:** below solution requires calling **private Apple API's**, which aren't allowed in AppStore submissions. Even though at this point in time Apple's automated checks aren't catching this, if that changes in the future (or a manual review catches the behaviour), your app might be blocked. Use this at your own risk.

To successfully make a short haptic by using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration`,you have to call a private method in AudioToolbox.But it's safe for today's App Store, cause my app using this technology has already passing the review.I'm believe that App Store reviewer does not concert about using this technology in your app.

To make it, you need a [objective-c class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397532/implicit-declaration-of-function-audioservicesplaysystemsoundwithvibration-is):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#import "vibrate.h"
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(int, id, id);

@implementation Vibrate

+ (void) vibrateMutate
{
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array ];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:50]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];


[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:.25] forKey:@"Intensity"];

AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict); //ERROR
}

+ (void) vibrateSectionChange
{
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array ];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:150]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];


[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:.75] forKey:@"Intensity"];

AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict);
}

@end
```

([raw objective-c version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822295/intensity-of-custom-iphone-vibration))

and a .m file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface Vibrate : NSObject

+ (void)vibrateMutate;
+ (void)vibrateSectionChange;

@end
```

Last, adding this line to the "YOU_PROJECT_NAME-Bridging-Header.h" file that Xcode about create for you!

```
#import "Vibrate.h"
```

Finally , you can call this method in you Swift code（if not working, relaunch your Xcode app might work）:

```
Vibrate.vibrateMutate()
```

**You'll get a short、Morden-style haptic in you dynamic island！**

Comment: "But it's safe for today's App Store, cause my app using this technology has already passing the review." that doesn't mean it's actually safe to use. Apple can at any point in time change their checks and ban your app (or in extreme cases your whole developer account) for using private APIs. So you should always clarify the risks involved in using a private API.

Comment: I agree. There are risks involved in calling a private API in an app. However, for most people, the answer provided is still helpful. The risk of using private APIs can be likened to a normal distribution. Based on my experience of developing multiple apps, the risk of using a private API to trigger vibration lies at the extreme ends of this distribution and can be considered negligible.